Drupal Data Retention and more
I was wondering if you can answer me broadly about how data retention works in drupal and if there is a difference to wordpress. I'm a CMS beginner.
I have been searching on drupals webpage, have not been able to find this kind of information there.

"Data retention" can mean a couple of things. One is "revisions", which is when you make a change and hit save. The other is user-data, and you'll see this in relation to regulations such as GDPR. Hopefully this helps your searches.
